# Authorization using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I trying role base authorization so as to control the access to database on the basis of the logged-in candidate is admin or user.

While creating permissions.js file I am getting an error that:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

The code in permissions.js is as follows:

```
/**Authorization Permissions**/

angular.module('fyiApp').factory('permissions', function($rootScope) {
  var permissionList = [];
  return {
    setPermissions: function(permissions) {
      permissionList = permissions;
      $rootScope.$broadcast('permissionsChanged');
    },
    hasPermission: function (permission) {
      permission = permission.trim();
      return permissionList.some(item => {
        if (typeof item.Name !== 'string') { // item.Name is only used because when I called setPermission, I had a Name property
          return false;
        }
        return item.Name.trim() === permission;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you share the actual error message with line number where the error is coming from?

Comment: The error is at the .factory() part i.e.
                        
angular.module('fyiApp').factory('permissions', function($rootScope)

Comment: But that line cannot have the error "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"